# I can't find 1.7.10

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I downloaded 1.7.10 installer I have the mod folder but I can't find forge release 1.7.10 in my launcher I tried looking everywhere for it.

Comment: How is not being able to find Forge in their Minecraft launcher technical support for modded Minecraft? Isn't the answer a simple "Forge is not part of Minecraft"?

Answer (score 3):

Forge is not part of Minecraft, and has to be downloaded separately.
[Here](https://files.minecraftforge.net/net/minecraftforge/forge/index_1.7.10.html) is a link to Forge for Minecraft 1.7.10.